# MQ maximum number of retries and backout threshold

Tags: jms, message-queue, ibm-mq

In WAS, I have created a jms queue X. I have also created another queue Y and in MQ, I specify that Y is backout queue for X.
Now for X if I say maximum number of retries :3 and backout threshold is 2, that means that after 2 tries if the message is not consumed by X, queue manager will put message on Y. In this case, maximum number of retries (3) will never be reached because it will never try a third time. And the listener for X will never go down.
Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not so sure about the jms interface, but in native WMQ, the queue manager does not automatically requeue the message to the backout queue.  it is up to the application to query the backout_count, compare that to the backout_threshold, and put the messages to backout_queue.

You should read "How WebSphere Application Server handles poison messages" -- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0405_titheridge/0405_titheridge.html

Also important to read "Best Practices: WebSphere MQ shared queues and application programs", scroll down to Issue 6 -- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0512_elkins/0512_elkins.html

Comment: Both links are broken

Answer (score 0):

MQ JMS implementation does the job of moving a message to backout queue once the backout threshold set on the target queue is reached. If a backout queue is not specified, MQ JMS attempts to put the message onto the dead letter queue.

There is no retry concept in MQ JMS as far as I know. It might be something related to WAS/MDB.

Answer (score 0):

it is weird that if it is application's decision to requeue the msg to backout queue, why the backout threshold is defined in queue's property ? should't this threshold property be defined in application.

Very confusing.